# How to load a demo webpage from some remote location

Tags: apache, client-server, html

I have a simple job to do. I have developed a demo website on an external server (say whose ip is 10.182.208.22) and demo is present is /var/www/demo/ . How can I configure my apache server running on the server, so that anyone at any remote location may see the demo by may be typing a url on his browser?

Comment: Use a `VPN` tunnel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

Comment: I dont even need to have this demo made public (when VPN comes into picture). Even within the company, how can I do the above thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<iframe>`s.

**Usage:**

```
<iframe src="example_page.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand. Could you elaborate more ? Thanks

Comment: You need to show a website in your website. IFrames are used to open websitess inside a website!

Comment: No No. I am sorry if my question was confusing. I have a full website developed at one location (server) and want to see it from other location (client).

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui an IP starting with `10.x.x.x` is private. You cannot include a page under that IP with an Iframe unless you're in the same network. It's like you tried to include an iframe from `127.0.0.1`

Comment: yes. But if someone else is also on the same network, then he should be able to see that, right ? So for such cases, I am trying to find an answer.

Comment: @Aryabhatt if some one is one the same network he will see that!